# binding List of objects to a list-oriented GUI component (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I Have (an instance of ) a class X that manages a list L of objects, and has it's own form to display some of it's properties. 
In my form I have a ListView and a TreeView objects, to which I write some attributes of L.
Later on, I'll like to respond to a click on an entity of ListView/TreeView , for which I need to resolve the entity's string back to the object it represents. 
What I do now, is to enumerate the objects of L , Looking for the one with that string,
but obviously it'll work only for unique strings. moreover, it seems like bad practice to enumerate like that, as I already had that information before, and also resources-wise.
My question:
Is there a way to bind L to the GUI component in a way that eliminate that situation?

thanks.

Comment: is this windowsforms?

Comment: Please add some relevant code, as it is very hard to understand your scenario

Comment: Add a reference to the object to the `Tag` property of `ListViewItem` or `TreeNode`.